# jQuery - how to make a one click event to stay permanent

Tags: jquery, wordpress

This is my code:

```
$('.to-add').one('click', function() {
               $(this).parent().toggleClass('cart-added');
                    $(this).css('display', 'none');         
 });
```

After the click event, the parent of the element gets a new class (as you can see in the code). Now what I'm trying to do is that the class being added would stay permanently, even if the page is reloaded, or if you go to other pages and then again to this one, the new class will always be there. Any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to use sessions to keep track of the state of the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Store added ID:s to a cookie or session. Then echo the class if the ID exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this with just JavaScript, you can use [JS Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) to store cookies locally (Client-side). You do this by saving whether or not the class has been added to the element as a cookie, then in your page load function you perform the necessary operations.

That being said, this isn't a **permanent** solution - if the cache is cleared, or if it's opened on a new browser, or if cookies are deleted, the class will not be added to the element as cookies are locally stored.

If you want this to to permanent, as in forever, you need to do that Server-side.

JavaScript is (generally) used for Client-Side logic - things that happen on the viewer's machine/browser, and can be different for all users. Frameworks like PHP, NodeJS (a JavaScript Server-Side framework), ASP/ASP.NET, and Ruby On Rails are used for Server Side logic - things that are saved/processed on the server and then displayed to the viewer.